# How to detect and handle API HTTP Response Codes

Tags: c#, http, soap, wsdl, httpresponse

I am using a C# Console App to interact with the DotMailer API.

The API returns [this][1] list of API Response Types.

I wonder how could I possibly detect these and then handle them in code?

For example in the block of code below, the function of `GetCampaignSummary()` may fail due to an Invalid_Campaign_Error, which would cause the program to trip over. How can I handle this without having the program quiting due to an exception?

```
foreach (var campaign in allCampaigns)
{
    if (campaign.Status == CampaignStatus.Sent)
    {
        if (campaign.Id == 111117)
        {
            var campaignSummaryData = api.GetCampaignSummary(UserName, Password, campaign.Id).DateSent;

            // Insert campaign data
        }

    }
}
```

Useful Link: https://developer.dotmailer.com/docs/error-response-types

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, it clearly at some stage will respond with a `HttpWebResponse`.  This would allow you to simply do the following `HttpWebResponse.StatusCode`.

Sample:

```
var request =  WebRequest.Create("...") as HttpWebRequest;
using(var response = request.GetResponse())
{
     if(response.StatusCode != 200)
     {
          // An Error...
     }
}
```

I'm fairly certain it implements, `IDisposable`.  But would be the general gist of access, without knowing for certain the `type` of those objects and variables, it will be quite difficult to assist you.